# How do I pass a function using "this" keyword into a JavaScript Class?

Tags: javascript, class

I have a class

```
class MenuItem {
  constructor(title, onPress) {
    this.title = title;
    this.onPress = onPress;
  }
}
```

When I invoke the constructor using `new MenuItem("MyMenuItem", (event) => { console.log(this.title); });` the keyword `this` is referring to scope that I'm creating the MenuItem in.

Is there a way to use `this.title` in the function I'm passing to my constructor?

Comment: In [**Arrow functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) it does say `An arrow function expression ... does not have its own this, arguments, super, or new.target. `

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I've read that section multiple times but it failed to click for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with an arrow function. Arrow functions dont have their own context (aka `this`) , so you need a regular one:

```
MenuItem("MyMenuItem", function(event){ 
  console.log(this.title); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
this.onPress = onPress.bind(this)
```

Comment: @Flying While this might work I don't think your `MenuItem` should have to worry about compensating internally for external "misuse". It also removes all flexibility and "hardwires" the context. What if a function is passed wanting to specify their own context?